# Absolute Position with 0 offset in all directions

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to learn html and css and I've been looking at various websites to practice.

This particular website (http://jsfiddle.net/Hexapod/CWB39/260/show/) had caught my attention but I'm having trouble figuring out how the elements here are working.

If you go to the website, there are "facts boxes" that were made using div elements. These div elements however, are grouped together by a another div element. This div element has an absolute position and an offset of 0px in all directions. Can anyone explain to me what the purpose of this is?

Here's what it looks like:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="factbox1" class="info">
    <!-- some code -->
  </div>
  <div id="factbox2" class="info">
    <!-- some code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

PS. If I'm doing something wrong with the formatting or anything, please inform me! This is my first time posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in place to stretch the element to the full extremes of the closest parent with `position` set. In this case, to extend the full height and width of the browser viewport.

Its basically telling the element that its top should meet the top side of its parent, its bottom should stretch to the bottom of its parent and the same for its left and right sides.

An alternative would be to use the below CSS:

```
html, body, #container{
 height:100%:
 width:100%;
}
```

The difference being that by using `position:absolute` the option for layering content is provided.

Comment: So let's see if I understand this. 

By doing that css above, the current dimensions of the (div id="container") is actually the dimensions of the viewport of the current browser.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes...or the dimensions of the closest parent with `position` set on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I've been thinking about this since last night and now you've answered my question clearly. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`inset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset) shorthand these days (not supported by IE of course)

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background: #002D62;
  inset: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="factbox1" class="info">
    Full with and height 
    <!-- some code -->
  </div>
  <div id="factbox2" class="info">
    <!-- some code -->
  </div>
</div>
```